# Peugeot 206 engine occasionally cutting out when idle

Tags: engine, peugeot, fuel-line, stall

Sorry if this is vague, I don't know very much, but I'll do my best. I want to have as much information possible before taking it to a garage to do anything. I have a 2003 Peugeot 206 1.1l which has done ~27000 miles. It's running pretty well, on the whole and the exhaust has recently been replaced for the 1st time.

On the way to work today, near the start of the journey, when I stopped in a queue of traffic the engine quietly cut out with no warning or stutter. I restarted the car and it was fine for a little while (including stopping again), and then it did the same again when I stopped. This happened for around about 20 minutes, with 3/4 'stalls' out of 9/10 stops.

I had a quick look on the internet, but not knowing the first thing meant that I couldn't make an informed judgement really. [This forum post](http://www.bba-reman.com/forums/topic46028-1-1.aspx), saying that it turned out to be a faulty engine control unit seemed to be the most similar to my case, although it's an older model. Another theory, based upon asking around, was air in the fuel line, which sounds like something that I might be able to fix myself if I can confirm that it is that somehow.

Does anyone know what might be wrong, or how to find out what might be wrong, before taking it to a garage?

Comment: Not knowing much about Peugeots, my *first* inclination is your idle air control (IAC) valve may not be working correctly (sticking or malfunctioning). Also, is the mileage you quoted correct? That is very few miles for an eleven year old car, though not unheard of.

Comment: @Paulster2 yes, the car was *actually* driven by a little old lady down to the shops once a week. My grandma is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like idle control valve I had same  problem on my Peugeot 206 gti when I started engine , it would cut out and I would need to turn over with accelerator. I would hold revs at 1000-1100 until warm after this would drive phone  but very lumpy when at roundabouts etc but would cut out 4/10 ten times 
cheers spence

Answer (score 0):

Your vehicles symptoms can be put down to several causes. A lot of 2003 - pre 2004 - Peugeots had end-of-run compoments of OBD1 vintage. You need to have a scan with a Peugeot Planet compatable scanner as a very first step. As GrandMa had the vehicle for some time she must have had a garage she used and had confidence in, perhaps you should use that garage. Most of the guff you hear about garages is just that - guff. I deal with many garages around the London(UK) area and they are all hard working honest and skilled tradesmen. With safeguards such as AA/RAC/CSMA membership, Small Claims Courts and not to mention The Office of Fair Trading, rogue garages have a hard time to exist. Costs of ownership of your Peugeot, doing 10000 miles a year, all in, would be around £50 to £75 per month.